# Using sqoop need to import the result of a query into hive table

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am able to import the entire table from a oracle db directly into hive table but not able to import the output of a query into hive table.  I added the query in the below command. Please suggest if any change in the command below. Thanks in advance.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@success.it.com --username ABCD --password 1234 --table students --query "select * from students" -m 4 --hive-import --hive-table mydb.students
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use single quotes instead of double quotes
2. add `--split-by <COLUMN_NAME>` to the command
3. add `WHERE $CONDITIONS` to your query

that should do the trick

```
sqoop import \
    --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@success.it.com \
    --username ABCD \
    --password 1234 \
    --table students \
    --query 'select * from students WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
    --split-by some_column_name
    -m 4 \
    --hive-import \
    --hive-table mydb.students
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me:
    16/03/17 20:33:59 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5-cdh5.4.5
    Cannot specify --query and --table together.

Comment: why would the --split-by be needed?

Comment: If your table has no index column, or has a multi-column key, then you must manually choose a splitting column by specifying `--split-by`

Comment: If you specify the -m 1 attributes, then you dont need to use split-by